# Get id from url in modal

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

In my case, I have a link with this structure:

```
 {foreach from=$listing item='item'}   
 <div>
                <ul id="saved-tables">
                    <li id="listing_{$item.ID}">
                        <a class="changeModal" href="#">{$item.Side}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

{/foreach}
```

When clicking on the link, open modal with select option and save button. After submitting the form need to save in database with (ajax) the new value of select form for defined listing ID. I get the value of select but how to get the ID from the link?

js:

```
   var $icon = $('#listing_' + id);
   var index = $icon.closest('#saved-tables').find('> li').index($icon);
```

But can't find the id from this form...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either supply the id the `id` to the markup in PHP using `$_GET['id']` or you could do it directly in javascript like:

```
let url = new URL(window.location);
let id = url.searchParams.get("id");
// let id = (new URL(window.location)).searchParams.get("id")
```

Comment: You're missing something before that `.searchParams.get("id");`

Comment: @CarlosCarucce thank you, completely missed that. I've updated the post.